# Powershell+Export-Excel module

Tags: excel, powershell, selenium

I use Export-Excel module for Powershell. I try to get results of "foreach" from 2 links in a table. But finally i have only one link in the table(only second one). "Out-File" has "=Append",that appends to a file. Maybe there is something like this for "Export-Excel"?

```
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom("C:\selenium\net40\WebDriver.dll")
$url = Get-Content D:\dww.txt
$ie = New-Object OpenQA.Selenium.PhantomJS.PhantomJSDriver
foreach ($u in $url) {
$ie.Navigate().GoToUrl($u)
$title = $ie.FindElementByXPath("//h1[contains(@class, 'fullstory')]")
$fullstory = $ie.FindElementByClassName("comment")
$tracklist = $ie.FindElementByXPath("//*[contains(@id,'news-id')]")
$links = $ie.FindElementByXPath("//*[contains(@class, 'link')]")
$img = $ie.FindElementsByclassname("stars").findelementbytagname("img").getattribute("src")

$h = Write-Output Стиль,Формат,"Год выпуска",Размер,"Название альбома",Исполнитель,Треклист,Ссылка,Обложка
$data = ($fullstory.text).split("`n") -replace ": ","=" | Where {$_.Trim()} | Out-String | ConvertFrom-StringData | Foreach {[pscustomobject]$_} | Select $h
$data.Ссылка = $links.text
$data.Треклист = $tracklist.text
$data.Обложка = $img
$data | Export-Excel d:\filedark2.xlsx -AutoSize
Write-Host $u " - выгружено"
}
$ie.Quit()
```

Answer (score 1):

if you're only using export-excel to save to a new excel document, you might try just exporting to csv using -append and converting to excel afterward with this

https://github.com/gangstanthony/PowerShell/blob/master/Save-CSVasExcel.ps1

```
...
$data | Export-Csv d:\filedark2.csv -Append -NoTypeInformation
...
}
Save-CSVasExcel d:\filedark2.csv
...
```